# Scroll Postion not being saved in ListViews on 2.3 and lower devices?

Tags: android

I noticed that in my app when I start a new activity from my ListActivity the scroll position does not get saved when I return to the ListActivity. I am automatically brought to the top of the list. However, the position of my ListView is automatically saved on my new 4.0 and above devices. Is this a known issue or would it be something I am doing within my application?

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong. In my onResume I was modifying the dither settings of my listview which was causing it to not save the scroll position. I removed this and it works fine. Not sure why it works on newer devices though :( If anyone has any ideas let me know.